# Creating Multiple Alarm?

Tags: android

Trying to create multiple Alarms using unique `PendingIntent` . However I am having trouble with this,

From MainActivity I press a button to set an Alarm, and the code for that is:

```
public void alarmSet(View view)
{
    int idTime = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AddAlarm.class);
    intent.putExtra("pendInt",idTime);
    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, AddAlarm.class));
}
```

Taking System time as unique id I am passing the value to the other activity from which I call the Broadcast to initiate alarm. Code for this Activity is:

```
Intent receive = getIntent();

pen = receive.getIntExtra("pendInt",0);
```

And here is the method in which I set the alarm.

```
private void setAlarm(Calendar targetCal)
{


    Intent alarmintent = new Intent(AddAlarm.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(AddAlarm.this, pen, alarmintent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, targetCal.getTimeInMillis(), sender);


}
```

This works for single alarms , however it doesn't generate multiple alarms. What might be the possible reason? Any help will be appreciated. Do I need to post the Broadcast class as well ?

Answer (score 0):

you are making `Intent` and putting extra but passing another `Intent` to `startActivity()`
just replace this

```
startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, AddAlarm.class));
```

to this

```
startActivity(intent );
```